# Icon does not appear in Windows Taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I work on WPF application and I finishing it, but I notice that when I run the application, the application Icon does no appear in Windows task bar ?

[image]

Although I assigned icon for my application in application properties.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance
Abdusalam

Comment: Whats the file extension of the icon which you try to assign? It should be .ico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the specific window an icon in your XAML or code behind for an icon to show when debugging.

```
<Window
    Icon="icon.ico"
</Window>
```

Comment: Yes, this needs to be done for each window you would like to display an icon in.

Comment: Thanks Cyral for helping me, Yes your answer is right but you directly type the icon name : Icon="OrderSystemIcon.ico". Thanks again :)

Comment: Your right, I copied it directly from my own project where it was a directory back.

Answer (score 0):

add ShowInTaskbar="True" in window like below

```
<Window ShowInTaskbar="True" > </Window>
```